# React onChange not being triggered from dispatched event

Tags: reactjs, events

I am trying to trigger `onChange` for a textarea by calling `dispatchEvent` on a ref that gets passed to the textarea.

The textarea:

```js
<textarea
    onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
    className={`${classes['text-input']}${
        error && touched ? ` ${classes.error}` : ''
    }`}
    ref={textAreaRef as MutableRefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>}
    rows={numberOfRows}
    cols={numberOfCols}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    id={id}
    value={content}
></textarea>
```

The code firing the event:

```js
const changeEvent = new InputEvent('change', { bubbles: true });

textAreaRef.current?.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

I have tried both `input` and `change` as the event types used for the event and neither have been caught by `onChange`. I know both from debugging and the behavior of my code that `textAreaRef.current` is defined, so that can't be what's causing `onChange` not to get called.

Why aren't the events I'm dispatching getting caught by `onChange`?

Comment: Can you give some more context on *why* you want to do this? Generally, it is quite an odd thing to do. Just in case there are more standard ways to achieve what you are wanting.

Comment: ALso if you could share the wider context of where `dispatchEvent` is called, as that's highly important here? Is it in another handler or an effect?

Comment: @adsy Now that I think about this, I think there may be a better way of doing what I'm trying to do. However, the context is that I'm creating a button that bolds text in the textarea (it's markdown). The `onChange` button calls Formik's `handleChange` function with a change event. Since I can't manually create react synthetic events, my idea was that I would try to fire off a manual event to trigger the `handleChange` that was being passed to the textarea.

Comment: Yeh, this is the wrong approach to achieve this and will lead to a nightmare. Let me post an answer based on that info, give me some mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, the right way to achieve what you want is not to trigger events but to manipulate the `Formik` store. It would be very opaque to attempt to do this by programmatically calling events and using element refs to do manual DOM calls like this is generally seen as a last-ditch desperate escape hatch.

If you are looking to set the value based on some other action, just call  `setFieldValue` from formik. You can get this from context (or render props, or `useForm` if you do it that way instead of `<Formik>` -- there are many ways):

Change `yourFieldName` to the formik name for this field that represents where it is in the state. And of course, you need to impl `getBoldText`.

```
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik'

// ...

const { values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext()

// ...

<button onClick={() => setFieldValue('yourFieldName', getBoldText(values.yourFieldName))}>Bold text</button>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing. It worked right away as opposed to hours of trying to figure out why my events weren't being handled. Thanks!